# importing kml with gx:track to fusion tables

Tags: gps, kml, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to upload a kml file created by [gpslogger](http://mendhak.github.com/gpslogger/) to google fusion tables, but the data will not import.

The data is structured using the [gx:track](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxtrack) element and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document><name>2012-07-25T00:43:29Z</name>
<Placemark>
<gx:Track>

<when>2012-07-25T00:43:29Z</when>
<gx:coord>-42.41141004 18.05962572 18.700000762939453</gx:coord>

<when>2012-07-25T00:45:50Z</when>
<gx:coord>-42.41167598 18.0596267 -3.100000381469727</gx:coord>

...

</gx:Track>
</Placemark></Document></kml>
```

When I try to upload it I get 3 empty columns: desription, name, and geometry.

So what's the problem?

I'm not familiar with any these tools, so hopefully I'm not making a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FusionTables KML support](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide#KML)  does not include the gx: namespace.  To import that into FusionTables you will need to convert it to "normal" KML.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was worried about but was having trouble finding it in the documentation.